# TV-Shows tag, should it stay or should it go?

Tags: discussion, tags

We actually blacklist the [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) tag because it is felt as too *meta* of a tag and has limited use.

Do we want to do the same to [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows)?

Comment: Brun it with the flame of a thousand suns.

Answer (score 6):

I largely agree with Christian Rau's answer, but I also know from experience that if we have such a generic tag, it'll largely be misused by users who don't know better.  I propose that we remove [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows), and then make one that covers the questions about *TV shows* as a topic, which he provided some examples of.  Maybe [tv-show-production](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-show-production), or something along those lines.  This will provide a more specific tag to use, while ensuring we don't have to constantly prune the [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tag as it keeps getting misused.

Comment: i like this. solves both issues

Comment: +1 Interresting idea.

Comment: wouldn't this then be covered by the [tag:production] tag?

Answer (score 1):

It should definitely be bruned :-)

Answer (score 1):

While many questions tagged with [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) don't really deserve it, being about a particualr show or about identification, there are also many that are indeed about *TV-Shows in general* and thus have a perfect right to bear the [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tag.

Some examples of IMHO justified [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tags:

- [Why are there typically no more than 24 episodes in a TV Season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8561/49)
- [Is the "season" meant to be the interval from September/October to May/June or is it not strictly defined like that?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9344/49)
- [How does the budget breakdown for a US TV season compare to a UK TV Season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9558/49)
- [Is there a term for the opposite of the Chuck Cunningham Syndrome?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9595/49)
- [What happens to actor salaries around seasons 6-7 of a show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10156/49)
- [What rules govern how TV show opening credits are structured?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1468/49)
- [In opening credits for TV shows, why does it say 'with so and so' for some actors?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1551/49)
- [When/Why did American television change from primarily episodic to primarily serialized?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3147/49)
- [Why do TV networks air pilot episodes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/4387/49)
- [What is meant by bloopers and marathon?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/7956/49)

So I don't see a reason to eagerly delete tags just because they can be misused for many questions they don't apply for. It rather should be decided on a question by question basis.

Comment: Largely agree with you.