# Television and TV Shows

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Following on from [my initial post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5603), would it be possible for us to discuss [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) and [television](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television)?

Did you know that we actually **blacklist** the movies tag? We explicitly ban the use of movies but we have got two television tags! Furthermore, [we've already had the discussion on removing the [tag:tv-shows] tag and agreed to remove it but never actually got rid of it](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/944/5603)...

So... here's a breakdown of the two tags we're discussing:

The tag wiki for [television](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television) says:

> General questions about the nature, problems and impact of television.

The questions themselves look to be similar in nature to those tagged [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) and I'm not even sure that the "nature, problems and impact of television" is even within our scope?

The tag wiki for [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) says:

> A segment of one-off or recurring content intended for broadcast on television. To be used on general questions about TV-shows, not for questions about a specific TV-show.

Looking through the questions, there are many instances where the tag is used in conjunction with a name tag - in these instances we'd be removing the tag anyway as per the existing tag wiki.

These tags are also misused heavily, especially on identification questions.

In many instances, the [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tag could be removed entirely and replaced with another tag.

I personally think we should remove both of these tags (after editing suitable replacements into place) and then black list both tags, like we have with [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies).

If the question is about a TV show or a movie but not about a particular work, it will always be in the context of something that should be covered by our other tags.

What do you think?

Comment: *"in these instances we'd be removing the tag anyway as per the existing tag wiki"* - Not necessarily, though. It could still be a question about the general TV-production-related problems of the specific work. But interesting question in general.

Comment: The tag wiki clearly states *not for questions about a specific TV-show*? Well, tag wiki's is a future discussion anyway, they're open for change.

Comment: Yes, please kill off these ridiculous tags. It's in our community's *title*, for Pete's sake.

Comment: I'm not sure though, if we still want `television` for the really general TV stuff that doesn't really seem to fit other production things. Maybe many things might fit `distribution` but that word somehow feels inaccurate for such general "airing" problems. But Ok, we don't have a `cinema` tag either and general cinema things would probably fall under `distribution`, too. Oh wait, we also have `scheduling`. Well, I guess that might also be a good fit for many of the things that I thought we'd need `television` for.

Comment: That's the point - we don't have a movie tag and we manage without that by using our other tags - I'm not saying that no additional tags might be created as a result of removing these two, but if they are they'll be for a very specific area that isn't already covered by our other tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally think we should remove both of these tags (after editing suitable replacements into place) and then black list both tags, like we have with [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies).

If the question is about a TV show or a movie but not about a particular work, it will always be in the context of something that should be covered by our other tags.