# Conflicting and confusing ratings tags!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating) - this is for questions about content ratings for movies.

We also have [television-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-ratings) - this is for questions about viewer ratings.

Since [we're cleaning up the [tag:tv-shows] and [tag:television] tags](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1762/5603) and [we currently need to differeniate between a movies and a television ratings tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19822/has-a-tv-showrunner-ever-blamed-u-s-television-content-rating-standards-for-com#19822) can we rename both of these tags to make it clear what they're about?

For [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating) I'm proposing [content-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-ratings) with an appropriate tag wiki. This will be used for both TV show and Movie content rating questions.

For [television-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-ratings) I figured we could rename this to [viewer-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer-ratings)?

What do you think?

---

Results:

- [television-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-ratings) is now [audience-measurement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience-measurement) with synonym [viewer-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer-ratings).
- [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating) is now [content-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-rating) with synonym [certificate-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate-rating).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the current wording might be a bit confusing and inappropriate.

**[movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating) should indeed become [content-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-rating) to better apply to the domain of TV shows**. I would however prefer singular to plural here, on the one hand to further distinguish it from the other kind of rating (for which the plural term "ratings" established itself as a common name) and because it better highlights the process of rating something and not the fact that it is a multitude of ratings that's the outcome, as it is with the other kind of "audience ratings".

Turning [television-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-ratings) into [viewer-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer-ratings) might not be as urgent, but I might agree that **it further helps to differentiate it from content rating and clarify its meaning**. That tag actually once was [nielsen-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nielsen-ratings), but while this was quite explanatory and clear *for those who know it*, it was far too specific and localized for an international site. So I turned it into the broader [television-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-ratings) which I agree might not be as clear as [viewer-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer-ratings). (Afterall, [viewer-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer-ratings) seems to be a special sub-tag of [reception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reception) anyway, but I think it's worth its own tag, seeing how broad [reception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reception) is in the first place.)

One could even go a step further and call it something like [audience-measurement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience-measurement) to better distinguish it from content rating, but I don't think that would help the explanation, since it seems a bit too abstract and afterall the word "ratings" has established itself as accepted terminology for a TV-show's performance. Or maybe we could use [audience-measurement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience-measurement) and make [viewer-ratings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer-ratings) a synonym of it.

Comment: I chose viewer ratings because a quick Google indicated they were known by that. Not too fussed about plural or singular.

Comment: I see audience measurement is also used. I'm more interested in there being a change that clarifies the tags rather than what actual change is made. These seem sufficient for that purpose...

Comment: @Flyk Well, for viewer ratings plural's better anyway.

Comment: Seems audience measurement is the proper term. Nothing stopping us from creating synonyms for viewer ratings

Comment: Why not call "movie-rating" "certificate" (or "certificate-rating"), that's the generally accepted term around the world if we're using it in the context of  MPAA/BBFC/etc classifications. Then you can free up the "*-ratings" tags for scoring/rate-this-content usage.

Comment: @Kev Might be worth an answer really (even though I'm not entirely sure I agree, but it's an interesting idea nevertheless).